# Run one jQuery function on multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, element

I have problem with running one jquery function on two or more elements. It runs properly on the first element in the HTML code, but doesn't work properly on others.

I have this jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$('.background_square_1 li.bg_square').hide();

function rotate() {
$(".background_square_1 li.bg_square").first().appendTo('.background_square_1').fadeOut(500);
$(".background_square_1 li.bg_square").first().fadeIn(500);

setTimeout(rotate, 10000);
}
rotate();
});
```

And HTML like this:

```
<ul class="background_square_1 gallery_background">
<li class="bg_square bg_1"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_2"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_3"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_4"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="background_square_1 gallery_background">
<li class="bg_square bg_1"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_2"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_3"></li>
<li class="bg_square bg_4"></li>
</ul>
```

Basically, what I am trying to achiveve is to run the function on both (but can be more!) ul elements with background_square_1 class.

Truth be told, I do not work with javascript or jQuery, so please keep this in mind.

Here is Fiddle showing my problem: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bWHPg/

Answer (score 1):

Just target that class directly. So for example

```
$(".gallery_background").function()
```

Or, if the function can't be called like that and you want to process each element with something else you could do

```
$(".gallery_background").each(function(index, item){
    var elm = $(this);
    ... Do stuff ...
})
```

I could have got index and item the wrong way round but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code inside document.ready rather than window.load

```
$(function() {
   //jQuery code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove .first() in your code your code would work fine

working fiddle here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bWHPg/2/

Comment: This almost works the way I want: It runs on multiple elements with the same class. However, you can se what it does: it doesn't fade in and out perfectly: when the first image is shown and it's about to fade out, it shows the second image for a second, and then fades out the first image, which does look bad. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: OK, I got it working: fiddle here:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bWHPg/3/

As maverickosama92 suggested, remove .first() and adding .hide() was everything I needed.
Thanks for suggestions guys!

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/bWHPg/5/

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $('.background_square_1').find('li:first')
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
         .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo(".background_square_1");
},  500);
```

Comment: Here, it doesn't fade in and out from picture to picture.